# Implementing a functional/persistent dictionary data structure

Tags: c, data-structures, functional-programming

I'm trying to implement a functional dictionary in C. It is fairly easy to implement functional lists or b-trees but I can hardly find any references on dictionaries/associative arrays.

I had a look at erlang's dict implementation - in the source code they refer to this paper:
[The Design and Implementation of Dynamic Hashing for Sets and Tables in Icon](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.14.5908&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

It would be great if someone could briefly explain erlang's approach or another solution to this problem.

Answer (score 6):

The implementation of a persistent data structure in C works basically the same way as it does in a functional language.  Chris Okasaki's [Purely Functional Data Structures](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf) is a great reference.

In general, it suffices to map fixed-width integers to objects, because 
while that doesn't give you a full-fledged dictionary by itself, you can build a dictionary on top: Use a hash of the actual key as the key of the underlying map, and have the leaves point to lists of (key, value) pairs of the same hash value.

The tricky part is memory management, since you don't generally know when parts of the data structure become unreachable.  Luckily, since most persistent data structures are based on trees, reference counting usually works well.  In order to be able to manage the objects referenced by the data structure, you can provide a hook for callbacks that get called when a leaf node's reference count becomes 0.

For example, my C implementation of bitmapped [Patricia Trees](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.37.5452) provides the following API:

```
// Querying
void *bpt_get(bpt_t bpt, bpt_key_t key);
bool bpt_has_key(bpt_t bpt, bpt_key_t key);

// Adding and Removing Entries
bpt_t bpt_assoc(bpt_t bpt, bpt_key_t key, void *item);
bpt_t bpt_dissoc(bpt_t bpt, bpt_key_t key);

// Managing Memory
void bpt_retain(bpt_t bpt);
void bpt_release(bpt_t bpt);
void bpt_dealloc(bpt_t bpt);
void bpt_set_dealloc_hook(bpt_t bpt,
                          bpt_key_t key,
                          void (*hook)(bpt_key_t key,
                                       void* value));

// Iteration
void bpt_for_mappings(bpt_t bpt,
                      void (*thunk)(bpt_key_t, void*, void*),
                      void *user_data);

// Making a Map Persistent (you can elide this if you don't
// want to support transients)
void bpt_seal(bpt_t bpt);
```

The [implementation](https://matthias.benkard.de/journal/118) might give you some ideas, too.

Comment: thanks for your response! The memory management is not my problem - I already have written a tree implementation using reference counting.
What I'm looking for is a functional dictionary implementation - a data structure with constant lookup-time. Trees usually only give logarithmic lookup complexity.  
I couldn't find any references to dictionaries in Okasaki's paper either.

Comment: @mirkok If lookup time is the only thing that matters, you can, of course, simply use a hash table and copy it on every update.  It's always a tradeoff.  That said, tries can be tweaked in this regard by the use of bitmapping (my implementation does; Clojure's PersistentHashMap does; others probably do as well).  With bitmapping, access is still logarithmic, but the base is larger.  This (in theory, but not always in practice) increases copying overhead, but reduces the number of hops you need to get to a leaf.  (With a 32-bit bitmap, 2^32 keys correspond to a maximum of 7 levels.)